# Get Google contact list via usernam and password

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I had read google tutorial about getting the contact list via  [google contact api v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)

but it requires to create an account on https://console.developers.google.com because google want to authenticate users when they use their api. I see this way make user have to press "Accept" before getting the access code.

Is there a way to get full the contact list just via google email and password on C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there is not an other way to get the full contact list.

Comment: After researching and testing, I agree with your answer